# Where is the function get_size?

Tags: c++, allocation

I'm reading the book *C++ Primer 5th Edition*. On *Page 477* a function `get_size()` is used to allocate an array of `int` , as pasted below.

```
// call get_size to determine how many ints to allocate
int *pia = new int[get_size()]; // pia points to the first of these ints
```

I have tried:

```
#include <new>
#include <memory>
```

but didn't work. I googled this function as well, but still in vain.Which header should I include before it can be used in my code?

Comment: It is surely an example function. Otherwise, what value could it possibly be expected to return?

Comment: This is embarrassing..Why am I so stupid...

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking the question. I got confused as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_size()` should be an **user defined function** here. Don't need to waste your time finding its header.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a random thing the book used as a example of the type of information to pass to `new`, e.g., the amount of the memory to allocate. It's not an actual function, at least not in the standard library.